# How to store stl objects in shared memory (C++)?

Tags: c++, stl, shared-memory

I've the following code pattern:

```
class A {
    double a, b, c;
    ...
};

class B {
    map<int, A> table; // Can have maximum of MAX_ROWS elements.
    ...
};

class C {
    B entries;
    queue<int> d;
    queue<int> e;
    ...
};
```

Now I want to store an object of type C in a shared memory, so that different processes can append, update and read it. How can I do this? (Note: I know how to store a simple C array that has a fixed size in shared memory. Also, remember that B.table may have arbitrary entries.

Comment: This is not easy. You'd need a special allocator for all your containers that knows about the shared memory. In C++11 this is slightly easier to implement thanks to stateful allocators, but it's non-trivial in any event.

Comment: I'm using i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2. Do you guys need more information about the specific compiler or platform?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [boost::interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/interprocess.html), this library exposes this functionality.

EDIT: Here are some changes you'll need to do:

The example already defines an allocator that will allocate from the shared memory block, you need to pass this to the `map` and the `queue`. This means you'll have to change your definitions:

```
class B
{
  map<int, A, less<int>, MapShmemAllocator> table;

  // Constructor of the map needs the instance of the allocator
  B(MapShmemAllocator& alloc) : table(less<int>(), alloc)
  { }
}
```

For `queue`, this is slightly complicated, because of the fact that it's really just an adapter, so you need to pass in the real implementation class as a template parameter:

```
typedef queue<int, deque<int, QueueShmemAllocator> > QueueType;
```

Now your class `C` changes slightly:

```
class C
{
  B entries;
  QueueType d, e;

  C(MapShmemAllocator& allocM, QueueShmemAllocator& allocQ) : entries(allocM), d(allocQ), e(allocQ)
  { }
}
```

Now from the segment manager, construct an instance of `C` with the allocator.

```
C *pC = segment.construct<C>("CInst")(allocM_inst, allocQ_inst);
```

I think that should do the trick. NOTE: You will need to provide two allocators (one for `queue` and one for `map`), not sure if you can construct two allocators from the same segment manager, but I don't see why not.

Comment: I looked at it before. I've never used it before, so was a bit hesitant. Can you please give me a rough idea on how I would have to adapt the code on the link below to meet my requirements. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html#interprocess.quick_guide.qg_interprocess_map

Answer (score 4):

Building and using STL objects in shared memory is not tricky yet (especially using boost::interprocess wrappers). For sure you should also use syncing mechanisms (also not a problem with boost's named_mutex).

The real challenge is to keep consistency of STL objects in a shared memory. Basically, if one of the processes crashes in a bad point in time, it leaves other processes with a two big problems:

- A locked mutex (can be resolved using tricky PID-to-mutex mappings, robust mutexes (wherever available), timed mutexes etc.
- An STL object in the inconsistent state (e.g. semi-updated map structure during erase() procedure). In general, this is not recoverable yet, you need to destroy and re-construct object in a shared memory region from the scratch (probably killing all other processes as well). You may try to intercept all possible external signals in your app and crossing fingers hope everything will go well and process never fail in a bad moment.

Just keep this in mind when deciding to use shared memory in your system.

UPD: check shmaps (https://github.com/rayrapetyan/shmaps) project to get an idea of how things should work.

Answer (score 3):

This can be tricky.  For starters, you'll need a custom allocator: Boost
Interprocess has one, and I'd start with it.  In your exact example,
this may be sufficient, but more generally, you'll need to ensure that
all subtypes also use the shared memory.  Thus, if you want to map from
a string, that string will also need a custom allocator, which means
that it has a different type than `std::string`, and you can't copy or
assign to it from an `std::string` (but you can use the two iterator
constructor, e.g.:

```
typedef std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, ShmemAllocator> ShmemString;
std::map<ShmemString, X, std::less<ShmemString>, ShmemAllocator> shmemMap;
```

with accesses like:

```
shmemMap[ShmemString(key.begin(), key.end())] ...
```

And of course, any types you define which go into the map must also use
shared memory for any allocations: Boost Interprocess has an
`offset_ptr` which may help here.